# Need help parsing a specific type of page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok so just for reference I will be using the liquipedia API to parse [this text area](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/index.php?title=Clarity&action=edit)
my question is how when i have a line like `|title4=Nearby Cast Range       |value4=500` parse that into a key value hash like {"Neraby Cast Range" => "500"}

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) to parse an individual line.

```rb
line = "|title4=Nearby Cast Range       |value4=500"

pattern = /\|title4=(.*)\|value4=(.*)/
matches = pattern.match(line)
title = matches[1].strip
value = matches[2].strip

myHash = {}
myHash[title] = value

#> puts myHash
#> {"Nearby Cast Range"=>"500"}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

For any number after the `title` or `value` fields, you could add `\d*` to the regular expression:

```
pattern = /\|title\d*=(.*)\|value\d*=(.*)/
```

That will work for `title0`, `title4`, `title123`, etc.

Comment: ok so if it had to be title* and value* what would you need to change?

so like 

title1 and value1      

title2 and value2

Comment: `pattern = /\|title\d*=(.*)\|value\d*=(.*)/`